# Issue reading preferences in android activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use the PreferenceActivity in a java app and I'm able to bring up a screen to modify the preferences but I'm unable to read the preferences in a nother activity in the same App.

I have one xml file under the xml/ folder called default_values.xml that contains just a single preference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<EditTextPreference
        android:key="json_url_pref"
        android:defaultValue="@string/json_url"
        android:title="@string/title_edittext_preference"
        android:summary="@string/summary_edittext_preference"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/dialog_title_edittext_preference" />


</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is the code I'm trying to use in my Activity to read the preference:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(EarningsActivity.this);
String tmp = sp.getString("json_url_pref","-1");
```

sp.getString(...) is always returning -1.

I think this is a contextual issue that for some reason this activity does not have access to the application preferences (at least my intention is to have the preferences be visible by all activities in the application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context that you're passing to `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` should be in the same package as the `PreferenceActivity` subclass that handles your preferences. Is that the case in your code?

Comment: Yes they are both in the package com.example.android.apis.view.    However my PreferenceActivity is a completely separate class. Does it need to be a subclass of the class where getDefaultSharedPreferences is called?

Comment: @opike: No, it does not. What you have there is fine, though it is possible you have problems elsewhere. Here is a sample project with a `PreferenceActivity` and another activity that reads the preferences: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/Dialogs

Comment: I discovered that I had to first go in and edit the field once in the emulator, and then after that the other activity could read the preference ok.

So now I just need to figure out how to get the initial state of the app to be such that it is able to read the preference successfully from the beginning, wtihout requiring the first edit.